# Kafka consumer can't connect to broker other than localhost:9092 using Spring Boot 2.2.0.M4

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.0.M4 and Kafka 2.2.0 trying to build an application based on the sample at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka. When I enable the listener for my topic, I get the following error on the consumer.

**[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.**

The following is defined in my application properties.

**kafka.bootstrapAddress=172.22.22.55:9092**

Here's the @KafkaListener annotated method.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "add_app", groupId = "foo")
public void listen(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received Message in group foo: " + message);
}
```

Below is the Consumer configuration class that is referencing the kafka.bootstrapAddress value. It is logged properly.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        log.info("Created {} using address {}.", this.getClass(), bootstrapAddress);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory("foo"));
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, at first I thought that it's a problem with my spring kafka endpoint configuration, but as it turns out I incorrectly configured the advertised listeners on my kafka. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867685/kafka-producer-is-connecting-to-localhost-instead-of-the-real-ip

Answer (score 6):

The solution to this is fairly simple. I just needed to add the following to the application.properties file.

**spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=174.22.22.55:9092**

After looking at KafkaProperties.java, I found this line:

```
private List<String> bootstrapServers = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList("localhost:9092"));
```

and this method actually builds them:

```
private Map<String, Object> buildCommonProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap();
        if (this.bootstrapServers != null) {
            properties.put("bootstrap.servers", this.bootstrapServers);
        }

        if (this.clientId != null) {
            properties.put("client.id", this.clientId);
        }

        properties.putAll(this.ssl.buildProperties());
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.properties)) {
            properties.putAll(this.properties);
        }

        return properties;
    }
```

Since it's already predefined on the class, the broker initially defined on the KafkaConsumerConfig is not used.

**Update**

Adding the containerFactory attribute to the listener annotation also fixes it and removes the need for the change to application.properties.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "add_app", groupId = "foo", containerFactory = "fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received Message in group foo: " + message);
}
```

Comment: You don't really need any of that infrastructure (consumer, container factories) unless you want some kind of advanced configuration. Boot will auto-configure them from properties.

Comment: In my case, `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=myserver:myport` in application.properties needed even after setting `ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` in ConsumerFactory properties. I guess it's a precedence rule.

Comment: I got the same issue when deploying Spring Boot app to K8s. My Spring Boot app has "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers: "kafka:29092"" but it shows "Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established". I replace "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers" with "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers" and it works. It seems like the kafka auto configuration favors "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers" over "spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers".

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your custom property `kafka.bootstrapAddress` you need to create @Bean `KafkaAdmin`. It has its own configuration class `AdminClientConfig` which is by default configured to connect to `127.0.0.1:9092`. To override the configuration you have to use something like this:

```
@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}
```