# Kafka producer is connecting to localhost instead of the real IP

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Please help I'm wondering why the kafka producer always connect to the localhost however there the broker ip is not the localhost. So, is there any help ? any ideas ?

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String bootstrapServers = "192.168.199.137:9092";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        // create the producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        System.out.println("kafka IP   " + properties.getProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG));


        // create producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("first_topic", "Hello world");


        // send data
        producer.send(record);
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();

    }

}
```

And here is the pom content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>KafkaBeginnersCourse</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
            <!--scope>test</scope-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is a list from the output console

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: 0TPD87gWR0G18RLKk4gPow
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Comment: Can you share details on Kafka setup? Could it be a listeners config issue?

Comment: I run kafka on Centos virtual machine, I just followed the same steps on the quick start  
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

If I package the application and run from inside the virtual machine is working fine. However when I run from Intellij from windows it is not working.

Comment: I suspect you need to alter `listeners` or add `advertised.listeners` config. Can you please update the question with a detailed description of the networking configuration and current broker config. Many thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems there is a problem in your `advertised.listeners` setting in `server.properties` file as @cricket_007 has already said. Let me try to explain it in detail.

When your producer try to connect Kafka broker, broker sends advertised hostname to client to use, then producer connect to broker with using this address. So normally communication is like this:

[image]

But in your case communication between producer and broker is like this:

[image]

P.S: You can assume public IP in images as private IP  for your case.

As a result you should set your advertised listeners in server.properties like this:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.199.137:9092
```

Reference for images: https://www.udemy.com/course/kafka-cluster-setup/

Answer (score 2):

`bootstrap.servers` discovers all the nodes, you can give just one address, though more are preferred.

Your client actually connects to the returned list of defined `advertised.listeners` for all the brokers.

Sounds like you're being returned localhost as those listeners.