# Confluent platform: connect ignore properties file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

i'm using confluent platform 5.4.0.

I've modified the `server.properties` file setting a static IP address for the broker, so i can access it with producers/consumers from remote machines.

Launching the platform with `confluent local start` the connect service starts but then goes timeout cause is unable to find a valid brokers, looking for a broker on localhost/127.0.0.1 also if i've updated also the `distributed-connect.properties` file with the same broker IP address.

Manually launching connect, pointing to the same file, then everything works fine.

It seems that from the confluent launcher the server.properties file was loaded but not the connect-distributed.properties

Now i'm working launching the connect service manually but i'm trying to figure if there's a way to launch everything with the confluent CLI.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your advertised.listeners setting in server.properties? Maybe this answer can be helpful btw : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874715/10550738

Comment: Thank you, but also advertised.listeners is set with the same IP. Also watching properties files in /tmp/confluent.[----] the kafka.properties has the correct brokers/advertised listeners value, with the static ip, but the connect.properties still has localhost. Relaunching confluent CLI the files were rewritten, so the "localhost" value is hidden somewhere.