# Error in kafka when consumed by a remote client

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka already work good in the localhost as consumer but, when i make a consumer in a remote machine I get the next error:

> [2020-02-06 11:53:22,172] ERROR Error when sending message to topic TopicTest with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for TopicTest-0: 2325 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

The conection between the remote machine and the server is fine because i execute the next command and work:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper my.public.ip:2181`

Comment: When you run localhost command for remote machine, check whether you are getting right IP. You might be getting IP of your own machine.

Comment: When executing this command I get the correct ip

Comment: Because you're providing it directly in the command. But when you say localhost, its up to the machine running the command to parse localhost

Answer (score 0):

You should check `advertised.listeners` config in `server.properties`. If it is localhost, then you should change it to broker ip address. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874715/10550738) answer can also helpful for you.