# Accessing Kafka installed on host from Java producer running in Docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, quarkus

I wrote a java based microservice which writes (Producer) to Kafka Queue. When I tested my microservice it is writing the data to Kafka correctly.

These were my settings that worked.

```
        "bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092",
        "TOPIC":"my.data",
        "PARTITION":"0",
        "key.deserializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "value.deserializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "enable.auto.commit":"false"
```

When I installed my microservice on the docker I changed my settings to

```
        "bootstrap.servers":"host.docker.internal:9092",
        "TOPIC":"my.data",
        "PARTITION":"0",
        "key.deserializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "value.deserializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "enable.auto.commit":"false"
```

Microservice is failing with the following error.

```
2020-11-19 18:41:14,958 WARN [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-11-19 18:41:14,967 WARN [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Am I missing anything? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap.servers` is used for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster. After this connection is established, broker sends `advertised.listeners` and producer uses this addresses to send messages.

In your case, as it can be seen from logs your `advertised.listeners` is `localhost`. That's why your docker container will try to access its own localhost.

Solution: You should also set `advertised.listeners` config in server.properties file to `host.docker.internal:9092` to connect from docker container.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874715/10550738) for more information.

Comment: This assumes host.docker.internal actually works... Been seeing issues with it, lately